# Count number of <li> tags in a <ul> on serverside using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a < ul > with some < li >(s). I want to count the number of these < li>s on server side. And if this number qualifies a given condition then i would like to add some more < li> elements to this < ul>. Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: What is source of these tags? is it HTML file or database record or something else?

Comment: where do you get your <ul>&<li>'s in the first place? is it taken from some sites? of you already generate it on that particular page/script?

Comment: Its HTML returned from a function of mine.

Comment: And that function can't include the extra data as well?

Comment: no i have to check for the number of li(s) from first function, and if they are less then a threshold, then only i need to include more li(s) from a different function

Comment: doesn't necessarily mean that the first function can't do it....

Comment: actually I am using two of wordpress plugins, if one plugin returns a count less than required then i use other plugin to fetch the data which returns just li(s) if i can just probably count the number of Li(s) in a ul. and then append an html (which will contain some li elements) at the end of that ul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's [DOM library](https://www.php.net/dom), or look up [Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).  They both have everything you need for manipulating and searching HTML to the extent of your question

Comment: Simple DOM Parser worked for me, had to play with it a lil but was fine :)
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

First a simple example using [php's DOM module](http://docs.php.net) and XPath

```
$s = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><title>...</title></head><body>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li><li>2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>x</li><li>y</li>
  </ul>
</body></html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml($s);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach( $xpath->query('//ul[ count(li)<3 ]') as $ul ) {
  $li = $doc->createElement('li', 'abc...xyz');
  $ul->appendChild($li);
}

echo $doc->savehtml();
```

and then an oversimplified example of what I meant by "And that function can't include the extra data as well?"

```
echo firstFunction(array('a'), 'secondFunction');

function firstFunction($arrData, $fnFill=null) {
  $rv = '';
  $counter = 0;
  foreach($arrData as $e) {
    $counter += 1;
    $rv .= '<li>'.htmlspecialchars($e).'</li>';
  }

  if ( 4 > $counter && !is_null($fnFill)) {
    // oh no. Not enough elements. Let's call $fnFill(), it provides some filler material
    $rv .= $fnFill();
  }
  return $rv;
}

// providing extra li elements
function secondFunction() {
  return '<li>x</li><li>y</li><li>z</li>';
}
```

Comment: I think if this solution is tweaked a lil then i can use it, actually I am using two of wordpress plugins, if one plugin returns a count less than required then i use other plugin to fetch the data which returns just li(s) if i can just probably count the number of Li(s) in a ul. and then append an html (which will contain some li elements) at the end of that ul.