# Counting the Number of items in a loop

Tags: php

So I need the program to count the number of items displayed in this loop.

```
foreach ($courses as $i=>$course) {
    print"
        <ul>
            <li> $course </li>
        </ul>
        ";
```

Comment: I think you will find a handy function in PHP called `count()`.... see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of <li> tags in a <ul> on serverside using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577171/count-number-of-li-tags-in-a-ul-on-serverside-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I imagine you are trying to show a unordered list of courses. So your code should look like the below code. Your current code would output multiple single list items. Also, as you are not using the arrays key you can lose the `$i=>`.

```
<ul>
<?php 
  foreach ($courses as $course) {
      echo "<li>" . $course . "</li>";
  } 
?>
</ul>
```

To count the amount of items in your array you can use `<?php $count = count($courses); ?>`. `count()` is a [PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) that counts the amount of items in an array. A more long winded solution would be to do the below code. This is simply incrementing a `$count` variable by 1 on every loop.

```
<ul>
<?php 
$count = 0;
foreach ($courses as $course) {
    echo "<li>" . $course . "</li>";
    $count++;
} 
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use the [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function.

Description:

```
int count ( mixed $array_or_countable [, int $mode = COUNT_NORMAL ] )
```